# Dependenciies in Gradle not working correctly

Tags: gradle, maven-2

We have a project that is using Java 1.5 and we are trying to convert from Maven to Gradle.

We have a repository that is local to us containing all the versions of all the jars we need as the dev environment has no access to the internet. 
The problem we are seeing is that it cannot find the commons-io jar and keeps trying to goto the external maven repo. we have not even set that up so where is it finding it from?

we have repositories and dependencies set up in the All projects section as follows

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'java'

 sourceCompatibility = 1.5
 targetCompatibility = 1.5
 project.tasks.withType(AbstractCompile, { AbstractCompile ac -> ac.options.bootClasspath = "C:/Program Files/java/1.5.0_14/jre/lib/rt.jar" })


  repositories {
     mavenLocal()
     maven { url "http://internalrepo/maven-local" }
  }

  dependencies {
     compile "org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2"
  }
```

But its reporting

```
 Could not resolve org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2.
   inconsistent module metadata found
```

even though it works fine in Maven using mvn install

Comment: maybe it is just mavenLocal() with capital L but im not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue,

Unbeknownst to me there was a hidden repo in the maven settings.xml in the maven install folder.

Adding that resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle will never query a repo that isn't set up. `mavenlocal()` is misspelled (should be `mavenLocal()`), which will make the build fail. "Inconsistent metadata" could mean that the group ID, artifact ID, or version in the POM doesn't match the one in the build script. `mavenLocal()` should only be used if the Gradle build needs to exchange artifacts with local Maven builds.

Comment: that line was added by gradle init when converting the maven project to gradle and its only mistyped on here. Also the projects call on each other in maven so rely on the jars built into the repo.

Comment: Next step is to inspect the POM and check if anything is wrong with it.

Comment: Also try with the latest Gradle version, to see if it makes a difference.